# convert css style - !important to muiStyle

Tags: css, material-ui

I'm using new `Material-UI` in my project. Now i'm converting old css files to new muiStyles.

I convert it in my muiStyle object with javascript like follows:

```
cont muiStyle={
  fabStyle: {
    display: 'none !important',
  }
}
```

But it doesn't work, please help.

Comment: Without !important it's working?

Comment: Please describe what doesn't work. Is it that the important doesn't get applied?

Comment: Please show the code that is using this style, explain what you want it to do, and describe what it is currently doing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 cont muiStyle={
      fabStyle: {
        display: none !important;
      }
 }
```

1. Instead of `,` you should use `;` in display.
2. You do not need to add `'` in display property.

Comment: actually this is not the solution. 
and it's not valid syntax in React muiStyle.